# List object return two separate List on append()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a function named "search_suggestion" that takes search parameter and pass into MySQL then a result is appended into an empty list "Suggestion" inside a function below

```
def search_suggestion(self,search,limit=25):
    """This method takes the parameter search return the search suggestion of employees in database"""
    cursor = None
    suggestions = []
    try:
        cursor = kasaa()
        cursor.execute(
            '''
            SELECT ospos_people.first_name,ospos_people.last_name
            FROM ospos_employees
            INNER JOIN ospos_people ON ospos_employees.person_id = ospos_people.person_id
            WHERE ospos_employees.deleted = 0 AND ospos_people.first_name LIKE %s OR ospos_people.last_name LIKE %s 
            OR ospos_people.phone_number LIKE %s OR ospos_people.email LIKE %s
            ORDER BY ospos_people.first_name ASC LIMIT %s

            ''',(search,search,search,search,limit)
        )
        row  = cursor.fetchall()
        for ro in row:
            suggestions.append(ro["first_name"]+ " " + ro["last_name"])
            print(suggestions)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

what am expecting is a list like `['alkhadil Issa', 'john Magufuli']` a one single list
instead am getting two list. 
`[alkhadil Issa']
['alkhadil Issa' 'john Magufuli']`

I have try to check `if len(suggestions) < 1:` before append `ro["first_name"]` but am not getting what i want. What is the most efficient way of doing this, any patient you can afford on my learning journey i would appreciate

Comment: Are you sure your SQL query is actually doing what you expect? Have you tried printing `row`, to see what is in there?

Comment: What is in the finally? You pasted invalid code.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse it `cursor.close`

Comment: @jhc SQL works fine my issue is on list as i said on my qns

Comment: Is suggestions `None` or is it the empty list? I don't see how `suggestions` could morph to `None`.

Comment: @JohnColeman it an empty list

Comment: That is what I thought, but then using the phrase "return None" is misleading since that has a specific meaning in Python. `None` is actually a built-in value.

Comment: @JohnColeman i appreciate the help John, but the list it return two list and none value as i explain on question i would be happy if you could edit

Comment: `row` isn't what you think it is. You said that the SQL works fine here, but that really doesn't seem to be the case. Since we don't have access to your data, I don't see how it is possible for us to know what the problem is. Perhaps you could tell us what `print(row)` prints.

Comment: That link is broken - either way no one would download the database and run your code. You have to `print(row)` in your own environment and paste the output in here so we can help you debugging your code. You can also try `print(ro["first_name"])` and `print(ro["last_name"])`, I'm sure the problem lies there

Comment: @GRoutar `print(row) = [{'first_name': 'Abdallah', 'last_name': 'Abdillah'}, {'first_name': 'Joseph', 'last_name': 'Magufuli'}]`  i have host my database online here - [http://07c9e8d6.ngrok.io/phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=kata]

Comment: @AlkhadhilIssa I added an "answer" with replicable code. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your problem by manually creating an output similar to what `cursor.fetchall()` returns according to you.

```
>>> dic1 = {'first_name': 'Abdallah', 'last_name': 'Abdillah'}
>>> dic2 = {'first_name': 'Joseph', 'last_name': 'Magufuli'}
>>> row = [dic1, dic2]
>>> row
[{'first_name': 'Abdallah', 'last_name': 'Abdillah'}, {'first_name': 'Joseph', 'last_name': 'Magufuli'}]
```

Assuming `cursor.fetchall()` returns something similar to the list above your code should work fine:

```
>>> suggestions = []
>>> for r in row:
...   suggestions.append(r['first_name'] + " " + r['last_name'])
...   print(suggestions)
...
['Abdallah Abdillah']
['Abdallah Abdillah', 'Joseph Magufuli']
```

If that is not the case, then your problem is your `cursor.fetchall()` result.

---

Edit:

I just realized your problem is getting 2 lists. Please be aware that your `print` statement is inside the `for` loop, so each time a value is added to the list, the resulting list is printed. If you only want to print the list in the end, just add the `print` statement after the loop ends:

So, instead of:

```
>>> for dic in row:
...     suggestions.append(dic['first_name'] + " " + dic['last_name'])
...     print(suggestions)
... 
['Abdallah Abdillah']
['Abdallah Abdillah', 'Joseph Magufuli']
```

Place the `print` outside of the loop:

```
>>> for r in row:
...     suggestions.append(r['first_name'] + " " + r['last_name'])
... 
>>> print(suggestions)
['Abdallah Abdillah', 'Joseph Magufuli']
```

Comment: ooh i understand now  perfect so i was return suggestions inside of a loop. I appreciate @GRoutar